# Hash Table Complexity

Tags: hash, time-complexity

I'm trying to figure out Best, Worst and Average Cases for Hash Table:
Hash table size m, input n size.

1. Finding a name in a hashed phone book with ‘average’ data, where
   collisions exist, but linear probing is the collision resolution
   scheme?
2. Finding the k-th argest item in a hash table that uses linear probing for collision resolution?
3. Finding the k-th largest item in a hash table that uses separate chaining for collision resolution?

My answers:
1. Best: 1 Worst:m Average:m/2
2. Best: 1 Worst:m Average:m/2
3. Best: 1 Worst:1+n Average:(1+1+n)/2= n?

I was thinking that any case search for one particular element in any ADT(Tree,Hash,Array) is always 1. Because, somehow magically you found what you need at O(1), I also thought that Average case is just Worst+Best/2. Is that right?

Correct me, if my thinking is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Worst Case O(n). It's the input size since atmost n probes can be there as you won't step on free location before reaching this value.
   Average Case and Best Case O(1).

If kth largest item refers to kth largest key present.

2. Worst Case: O(kn) Average and Best Case: O(k).
3. Worst Case: O(kn) Average and Best Case: O(k).